# Save script log in soap ui into one file without overwritting the output file

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui

I have a testcase in soapui (ver 5.4.0) with special setup script (below). This code works fine, every time I run my testcase, I'm getting all log.info from script log into my script.txt.

```
def logArea = com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.logMonitor.getLogArea("script log")
def LogFile = new File ("C:/Users/myuser/Documents/script.txt")
LogFile.write("Generating Script Logs...\r\n")
if (logArea != null)
{
    def model = logArea.model
    if (model.size > 0)
    {
        for (c in 0..(model.size-1))
        {
            LogFile.append(model.getElementAt(c).toString() + "\r\n")
        }
    }
}
```

But the main problem is, I want to store every run into one  every time I run new testcase, it overwrite my output file. But I want to keep everything, every run in one file, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my script, so I changed "write" to "append":

```
logArea = com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.logMonitor.getLogArea("script log")
def targetfolder = 'C:\\Users\\myuser\\Documents\\'
def logFile = new File (targetfolder + "setup_script.txt")

logFile.append("------------------------------------------------------------" + "\r\n")
if (logArea != null)
{
    def model = logArea.model
    if (model.size > 0)
    {
        for (c in 0..(model.size-1))
        {
            logFile.append(model.getElementAt(c).toString() + "\r\n")
        }
    }
}
```

It was easier than i thought.